# E-Mail wont open from windows 7 search

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, windows-search

sometimes an element wont open, of I click on it in the start menu in the search results. This occurs most when searching for emails. I use outlook 2007 on windows 7 x64. If I search in outlook for that mail I can simply double-click it an it opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the Project pro 2010 Beta installation corrupted my Outlook 2007 install regarding the search elements opened from explorer or start menu.